# Eclipse Plugins not appearing in Preferences, Views, or Perspective

Tags: eclipse, rest, maven, jira

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 Indigo, Java Developer IDE. I've installed Maven, RESTClient, e4HTTP. But, I do not see them in the Preferences, Views, Perspective. I've looked everywhere to figure out why and am completely lost. Is there something I'm missing? Is there a trick? Thanks... Thoroughly frustrated.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you installed these products I assume you meant that you installed the plugins for those products in Eclipse and not just on your machine.

Try these troubleshooting steps:

1. Open the plugin registry view (Window -> Show View...) and make sure the plugins you installed are listed.
2. Invoke Eclipse with the -clean park.  This will force Eclipse to refresh several chaches and this often fixes similar problems.
3. Open the Error Log view (Window -> Show View...) and click on the red X to clear the messages.  Stop and start Eclipse to see if any informative or otherwise helpful messages appear in the log.

Comment: I tried re-installing RestClient. It produced an error saying it was already installed. I'm using Windows. How do I clean the cache?

Comment: If you're invoking Eclipse via shortcut, open the properties on the shortcut to view the command that gets invoked when you open the shortcut.  Add "-clean" as an argument to this command, OK the changes and start Eclipse again.